UDP connection not recognized as UDP stream
A question from the VoIP sector.
Several devices behind NAT wants to establish UDP connections to a SenderIP.
The NAT settings for UDP are
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_udp_timeout = 30
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_udp_timeout_stream = 120

The device sends to the server a REGISTER and establishes a UDP connection.
The usual game follows:
->Proxy Authentication Required
<-REGISTER nonce
->OK

And in >99% this is recognized as UDP stream.
If the SenderIP now sends a SIP packet every 60 seconds, the connection always remains on the same port as a UDP stream.
I see in conntrack (e.g. for 2 devices):
udp 17 114 src=internalIP1 dst=SenderIP sport=5060 dport=5060 src=SenderIP dst=externalIP sport=5060 dport=8382 [ASSURED] mark=0 use=1
udp 17 119 src=internalIP2 dst=SenderIP sport=5060 dport=5060 src=SenderIP dst=externalIP sport=5060 dport=22919 [ASSURED] mark=0 use=1

However, I (rarely) have the case (here TTL 9 seconds down from 30, not recognized as stream)
udp      17 9 src=InternalIP dst=SenderIP sport=5060 dport=5060 src=SenderIP dst=ExternalIP sport=5060 dport=20932 mark=0 use=1

after a minute:
udp      17 26 src=SenderIP dst=ExternalIP sport=5060 dport=20932 [UNREPLIED] src=ExternalIP dst=SenderIP sport=20932 dport=5060 mark=0 use=1

Port is closed and device is unreachable from SenderIP.
When I analyze this case, I see on this dport (20932) with timestamps:
<-REGISTER:
15:17:41.728188 IP (tos 0x60, ttl 63, id 12923, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 621)
->Proxy Authentication Required:
15:17:41.732859 IP (tos 0x10, ttl 59, id 3219, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 527)
<-REGISTER with auth:
15:17:41.733459 IP (tos 0x60, ttl 63, id 12925, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 627)
->OK:
15:17:41.738826 IP (tos 0x10, ttl 59, id 3220, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 564)

in conntrack i can see TTL 9 seconds, this is NOT recognized as stream:
udp      17 9 src=internalIP dst=SenderIP sport=5060 dport=5060 src=SenderIP dst=externalIP sport=5060 dport=20932 mark=0 use=1

In total there are only 2100 connections, so no limit should be reached.
Why are some connections not recognized as streams?
What is the algorithm to recognize a connection as a UDP stream?
In which cases could it fail?
